# When using IIS Express through Visual Studio 2012, resx changes are not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

In my html code of a C# web application I have the resx references as:

ul class="inlineList"
    li
        fmt:message key="scrollabletable.footer" /
        span data-bind="text: firstDisplayedRowNumber() + '-' + lastDisplayedRowNumber()"
        /span
        fmt:message key="scrollabletable.pager" /
        span data-bind="text: itemCount">

The resx code:

```
<data name="scrollabletable.footer" xml:space="preserve">
    <value> Showing </value>
</data>

<data name="scrollabletable.pager" xml:space="preserve">
    <value> of </value>
</data>
```

When I view the website through ASP.NET VS Server, I can see the strings from resx displayed. But when I use IIS express, those ("Showing", "of") don't get displayed.

Any idea why?

Comment: have you try after IISRESET?

Comment: Even though you stop debugging your website, the IIS Express instance doesn't shut down. It may still have a stale DLL that contains the old resources. Try going to your system tray and clicking the arrow/chevron, right click any IIS Express instances that are running and click Shutdown. Then restart debugging.

Comment: While compiling I get "Unrecognized namespace fmt" - looks like it is related to that. I am not able to find a way to fix that. Anyhelp is appreciated.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Your particular problem is not with the RESX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About your last comment on your post:

It looks like you're using a namespace `fmt` on an attribute of a `li` element. Assuming you have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- some stuff here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some stuff here -->
    <ul class="inlineList">
        <li fmt:message key="scrollabletable.footer" />
        <span data-bind="text: firstDisplayedRowNumber() + '-' + lastDisplayedRowNumber()" />
    <span fmt:message key="scrollabletable.pager" />
    <span data-bind="text: itemCount"> 
    <!-- other stuff below -->
```

The problem is not with your RESX. It's with the `fmt` namespace on the `message` attribute. `fmt` is an unrecognized namespace in HTML since HTML has no concept of namespaces. XHTML, on the otherhand, has the concept of namespaces. When using XHTML, there's nothing stopping you from having other namespaces declared, either. I suggest trying the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fmt="urn:fmt-namespace-here" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- some stuff here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some stuff here -->
    <ul class="inlineList">
        <li fmt:message key="scrollabletable.footer" />
        <!-- NOTE: Instead of specifying the namespace in the html element, you could
                   also do the following:
        <li fmt:message key="scrollabletable.footer" xmlns:fmt="urn:fmt-namespace-here" />
        -->
        <span data-bind="text: firstDisplayedRowNumber() + '-' + lastDisplayedRowNumber()" />
    <span fmt:message key="scrollabletable.pager" />
    <span data-bind="text: itemCount"> 
    <!-- other stuff below -->
```

In the example above, you've declared your namespace `fmt` and now the document processor will know about it and recognize it.

**NOTE:** Since you didn't include spaces before your sample HTML in your OP, I sort of had to guess at what you wrote since all `<` and `>` disappeared, and possibly other content following those characters.

HTH.